# Bootstrap, data-toggle in ng-repeat, default to open and/or bind open to data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a bit of bootstrap html I am trying to integrate into my angular app. I am running a repeat on some data coming in and I'm trying to integrate it into this logic, So I'm basically just trying to default the tabs to open, and if possible tag them to a boolean.

So here is the html

```
<div>
<a data-toggle="collapse" ng-href="#{{filter.name}}" aria-expanded="true" >
    <h4>{{filter.name}}<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></h4>
</a>
<div class="collapse col-xs-12" id="{{filter.name}}">
    <div ng-repeat="item in filter.values track by $index" class="result-filter-value" value="item" update-filter="updateFilter">
    </div>
</div>
```

This works great, however changing the aria-expanded to true does nothing. The are still closed upon creation.

I'm also just wondering if I could bind it to something like a boolean like

```
aria-expanded="filter.isChecked"
```

Where that boolean would just return if the item is checked. I do not have the luxury of plugging in bootstrap-ui right now unfortunately, so I'm wondering if there is a quick and easy way to fix this, mainly have the toggles all default to open. Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about tabs or accordions?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg accordions

Comment: @DavidGrinberg as i mentioned, I cannot use bootstrap-ui in this project

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what exactly do u want but to toggle visibility of div with items, u could do

```
<div>
  <a data-toggle="collapse" ng-href="#{{filter.name}}" aria-expanded="true" ng-click="filter.showItems = !filter.showItems">
    <h4>{{filter.name}}<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></h4>
  </a>
  <div class="collapse col-xs-12" id="{{filter.name}}" ng-show="filter.showItems">
    <div ng-repeat="item in filter.values track by $index" class="result-filter-value" value="item" update-filter="updateFilter">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this will break in a repeat - it will open all of them

Comment: so just iterate over your filters and add showItems property to each.. then toggle that property

Comment: There is already  functionality show and hiding them that I am trying to work with - not re create . Thats what I mean by it will break. This will mess with bootstraps already working accordion logic that I am using. This completely circumvents the bootstrap, which I am trying to use.